# javascript function generates reference error in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

I have an anchor tag and I added an onclick function as follows:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" value="shift" onclick="changeButtonLabel(event, 'timeframe')">Shift</a>
```

the changeButtonLabel is defined in a js file that I attached at the bottom of the html file:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<script src="{% static 'dashboard/js/selectors.js' %}"></script>
```

the function is defined as follows:

```
window.changeButtonLabel = function(e, ddl){
var elems, selected;
elems = e.target;
selected = elems.innerHTML;

if (ddl=="timeframe"){
document.getElementById('timeframeDDL').innerHTML = selected + "<i class='fa fa-caret-down' aria-hidden='true' style='float:right;'></i>";
} else{}

}
```

but this function also works if i attached it inside a `<script>` tag at the beginning of the html file. I have tried to attach the js file at the beginning of the file but it also failed.

What is weirder is that the code works fine in firefox.

Below is the error generated:
[image: error]

Your help is appreciated.
Thanks!

EDIT:
**This problem is solved after I clear the browser cache! Thanks all for your helps! :)**

Comment: I put your code in [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/41Lyrx1e/) and tried it in Chrome and it worked.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to reference the element before it exists in the DOM. Put your code inside a `window.onload`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge - The error is saying that the function is not defined, not the element.